# Script needed for fetching files using wget

Tags: shell, cron, wget

I want to use cron for making wget fetch a newspaper on a daily base, which is everyday being uploaded as six PDF files, which follow the following string pattern: 2016.08.02-1.pdf, 2016.08.02-2.pdf [...] 2016.08.02-6.pdf
Actually that would be a good opportunity for me to practise scripting, but these days I'm really busy and I guess some people here could write the according few lines within a few minutes. ;)
So the cron entry should make wget being executed six times for each day's issue, so the script should 1) create a string for the according date (I guess that could be done by using the date command) and then 2) let wget fetch the six files by attaching "-" and the numbers 1-6 to the date string.

I'd really appreciate it, if someone could help me with that. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
   cur_date= date +"%y.%m.%d"
   for i in `seq 1 6`
   do wget [your options] https://your_host.your_domain:/your_request/$cur_date-$i.pdf
   done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. However, unfortunately the script I created based on what you suggested didn't work. Here's the script I saved:  #!/bin/bash
cur_date= date +"%y.%m.%d"
   for i in `seq 1 6`
   do wget http://<domain>:/directory/directory/$cur_date-$i.pdf
   done
It always results in wget trying to fetch "-1.pdf" without appending the date string. Any idea what the reason for this might be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A, sorry, skip the underscore, instead of cur_date, try $curdate. It should work.

Comment: Sorry, but the result is exactly the same when skipping the underscore. I'm able to understand how the script's code works, so I really wonder why it doesn't work.

Comment: I finally figured out how to do this:

Comment: 1) When assigning the output of the date command to "curdate", one has to enclose the command into apostrophes: curdate=`date +%y.%m.%d` 2) This alone still wouldn't work, since the filenames start with "2016", while date will return a string starting with "16", so the wget command has to be "wget [...]/20$curdate-$i.pdf" - I hope this helps anyone encountering similar issues related to bash scripting. Anyway thanks for having posted the original script!